# ActionButton to Filter Data for Modularized Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a reproducible example by simplifying an issue I am trying to solve for. I am attempting to:

1. Let a user select a table that they want to apply filters to
2. Create an actionbutton that lets the user select one or multiple filter criteria's by:

   - Selecting a numeric column from the selected table
   - Restricting the range of the column from a slider

I'm struggling to identify / fix my error. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# creating the actionbutton ui function
add.filter.UI = function(id) {

  ns = NS(id)

  tagList( # need to use taglist for multiple UI objects
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput(ns("sel_col")),
      uiOutput(ns("rng_filter"))
    )
  )

}

add.filter.server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    ns <- session$ns

    # identifies the table to use for selecting the column / filter range
    tbl = reactive({ eval(parse(text = df)) })

    # identifies column within tbl
    col.nms = reactive({ names(tbl() %>% select_if(is.numeric)) })

    # creating the dynamic column selection UI
    output$sel_col <- renderUI({
      req(col.nms())
      selectInput(inputId = ns("sel.col"),
                  label = "Select a column",
                  choices =  col.nms(),
                  multiple = F)
    })

    # selects the column from the df
    col.df <- reactive({
      req(input$sel.col)
      df <- get(tbl())
      df1 <- as.data.frame(df[,input$sel.col])
      df1
    })

    # creates the dynamic range filter UI
    output$rng_filter <- renderUI({
      req(col.df())
      sliderInput(inputId = ns("rng.filter"),
                  label = "Filter the range",
                  value = c(min(col.df(), na.rm = T), max(col.df(), na.rm = T)),
                  min = min(col.df(), na.rm = T),
                  max = max(col.df(), na.rm = T),
                  step = (max(col.df(), na.rm = T) - min(col.df(), na.rm = T)) / 1000) # 1,000 breaks
    })

    eval(parse(text = paste0("values$", input$sel.tbl))) <- eval(parse(text = paste0("values$", input$sel.tbl))) %>%
    rename(Var = one_of(input$sel.col)) # %>%
    filter(Var >= min(input$rng.filter), Var <= max(input$rng.filter)) %>%
    rename(!!input$sel.col := Var)

    return(values)

  })
}

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "sel.tbl", label = "Select a table",
                  choices = c("mtcars", "iris"),
                  selected = "mtcars", multiple = F),
      actionButton("add_filter", "Filter", icon = icon("plus"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      navbarPage(title = "Nav",
                 tabPanel("default",  tableOutput(outputId = "tbl"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values = reactiveValues(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris)

  # setting up the dynamic filter action button
  observeEvent(c(input$add_filter, input$sel.tbl), {

    id <- paste0("filter_", input$add_filter)

    insertUI(
      selector = '#add_filter',
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = add.filter.UI(id)
    )

    values <- add.filter.server(id = id, df = input$sel.tbl)
  })

  # displaying the table
  output$tbl = renderTable(

    eval(parse(text = paste0("values$", input$sel.tbl)))

  )

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. You still need to figure out what you would like to `filter`, and how to handle the change in dataset as the variable selection from the previous dataset becomes invalid.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# creating the actionbutton ui function
add.filter.UI = function(id) {
  
  ns = NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    #id = ns("break"),
    
    fluidRow(uiOutput(ns("sel_col")),
             uiOutput(ns("rng_filter"))
    )
  )
  
}

add.filter.server <- function(id,tbl) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
# creating the actionbutton server function
#add.filter.server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns <- session$ns
  values <- reactiveValues(mydf=NULL)
  #tbl = reactive({ eval(parse(text = input$sel.tbl)) })
  
  col.nms = reactive({ names(get(tbl()) %>% select_if(is.numeric)) })
  
  
  # creating the dynamic select column UI when the action button is clicked
  output$sel_col <- renderUI({
    req(col.nms())
    selectInput(inputId = ns("sel.col"),
                label = "Select a column",
                choices =  col.nms(),
                multiple = F)
  })
  
  col.df <- reactive({ 
    req(input$sel.col)
    df <- get(tbl())
    df1 <- as.data.frame(df[,input$sel.col])
    df1
  })
  #observe({print(col.df())})
  
  # creating the dynamic range filter UI when the action button is clicked
  output$rng_filter <- renderUI({
    req(col.df())
    sliderInput(inputId = ns("rng.filter"),
                label = "Filter the range",
                value = c(min(col.df(), na.rm = T), max(col.df(), na.rm = T)),
                min = min(col.df(), na.rm = T),
                max = max(col.df(), na.rm = T),
                step = (max(col.df(), na.rm = T) - min(col.df(), na.rm = T)) / 1000) # 1,000 breaks
  })
  
  # applying the column / range filter to the table per filter created from the action button - needs work
  values$mydf <- get(tbl()) # %>%
  #eval(parse(text = values[[input$sel.tbl]])) <- eval(parse(text = values[[input$sel.tbl]])) %>%
    # rename(Var = one_of(input$sel.col)) # %>%
    # dplyr::filter(Var >= min(input$rng.filter), Var <= max(input$rng.filter)) %>%
    # rename(!!input$sel.col := Var)
  
  return(values)
  
  })
}

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput(inputId = "sel.tbl", label = "Select a table",
                  choices = c("mtcars", "iris"),
                  selected = "mtcars", multiple = F),
      
      actionButton("add_filter", "Filter", icon = icon("plus")),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      navbarPage(title = "Nav",
                 tabPanel("default",  tableOutput(outputId = "tbl")),
                 tabPanel("filtered", tableOutput(outputId = "tbl.filtered"))
                 
      )
    )
    
  )
  
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  values = reactiveValues(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris, mydf=NULL)
  
  observe({
    if (input$add_filter==0)  values$mydf <- eval(parse(text = values[[input$sel.tbl]]))
  })
  # setting up the dynamic filter action button
  observeEvent(c(input$add_filter,input$sel.tbl), {
    id <- paste0("#filter_", input$add_filter - 1, "-break")
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      #selector = paste0("#filter_", input$add_filter - 1, "-break"),
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui =tags$div(  
        add.filter.UI(paste0("filter_", input$add_filter)),
        id = id
      )
    )
    
    value <- add.filter.server(id = paste0("filter_", input$add_filter), reactive(as.character(input$sel.tbl)))
    values$mydf <- value$mydf
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  # displaying the raw table
  output$tbl = renderTable(
    
    eval(parse(text = input$sel.tbl))
    
  )
  
  # displaying the filtered table from the action button
  output$tbl.filtered = renderTable(
    values$mydf
    #eval(parse(text = values[[input$sel.tbl]]))
    
  )
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, I was on vacation until now. Your solution does resolve the UI, but I could not figure out why the server portion is still going wrong. I have edited my initial question with my updated code. Would you be able to take a look again and provide either 1) insights as to what I am doing wrong or 2) corrected code.